# How do I link a library? (MySQL Library)

Tags: c++, linker

Alright, I am trying to Link this into my program and I never linked anything before so I need help with not only linking it (Because I have the directory in the linker -> additional directories but I need to link against the libmysql.lib/dll. I am not sure how to do that.

If you could give me a basic understanding that would be great! Just don't make it too complex ;)

I am trying to follow the steps on the website and it says to do this: (I have looked up and people said something about a MakeFile and I honestly don't know anything how that works)

> The Connector/C++ static library file is mysqlcppconn-static.lib. You link this library statically with your application. Also link against the files libmysql.dll and libmysql.lib. At runtime, the application will require access to libmysql.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do to install an library to your c++ project.

1. Add it to additional depencies in the linker.

Project->Properties->Linker->Input

Click the dropdown, click edit. On the list on the top, add just the names for every .lib file included in the library. For example, If installing SDL, one would add:

```
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib
```

These files can probably be found under the lib folder of the library you downloaded (look around a bit).

2. Tell VS where the header files are.

   Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories

Click the dropdown, click edit. add the location of all of the header files of the library. You can put them wherever you want, but it is suggested you put them in their own folder in your project folder somewhere. Wherever you put them, put the directory here; the containing folder, not the files themselves.

3. Tell VS where the lib files are.

   Project->Properties->VC++Directories->Library Directories

Click the dropdown, edit. Same thing as step 2, but you instead are putting the location of all the .lib files. Yep, the same ones you defined in step 1.

4. Provide the .dll files to your executable.

When the executable runs, it needs .dll in the same directory or it will not run (CORRECTION = It will run, but will give you an error upon open). So find your executable and put any .dll files in the same directory. How to find where it is by default:

Solution Explorer->Right Click Solution->Open in explorer->Debug

You should see the .exe there. Put the libraries dll files in that same directory.

If you have any questions please ask.

Comment: Thanks a ton, I am happy you took your time and let me know <3 I appreciate it greatly.